# A simple GIT workflow for tiny team

Tags: git, teamwork, workflows

I've just joined a project that a developper has been working on solo for 15 years. This is the first time he's had someone collaborate on a project. I've just convinced him we need version control on the project to collaborate effectively as it was entirely unversioned before (manual copies of code versions).
I've set us up using SourceTree with GIT. We both work on the same files in the program, but, we work on different days of the week.
Now we need the simplest workflow possible. It seems the centralized workflow might be best.

Our desired process:
Beginning of the day:
Download colleague changes.

Throughout the day:
Make our changes.

End if the day:
Upload our changes.

In GIT what's the equivalent of this?

My idea:
Stable release on master
Development branch for changes

Beginning of day:
git pull --rebase origin development

Throughout the day:
git commit (whenever we want)

End of day:
git push origin development

When release is ready:
Final commit tagged with version number.

Then Manager performs:

git checkout master
git merge development
git push origin master

Is this looking good and simple for our purposes, or is there an easier, simpler way for someone who doesn't like complexity adding to a (solo) workflow they've enjoyed for 15 years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the work flow with 2 people on a project](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98580/whats-the-work-flow-with-2-people-on-a-project)

Answer (score 3):

Git Flow. Its documented, well tested and SourceTree has buttons to simplify the process.

Your real problem is convincing your co developer that such things are needed. I  can understand why you think simplicity might be a good selling point, but so can 'officalness'

Comment: I like the look of gitflow, but the additional branching complexity seems like overkill when he's coming from unversioned code. I'll look into it further.

Comment: its somewhat counted by sourcetree's "start new feature" "finish feature" etc buttons

Comment: @KyoheiKaneko Branching adds simplicity,  not complexity. I use Git Flow for a *single developer workflow* and it works better than anything I’ve tried before (or since).

Comment: Intresting I will have to look into the sourcetree extension